# How to get output html in different language using gulp-data?

Tags: json, npm, internationalization, gulp, gulp-data

This is my gulp file

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var posthtml = require('gulp-posthtml');
var mjml = require('gulp-mjml');
var nunjucksRender = require('gulp-nunjucks-render');
var data = require('gulp-data');



gulp.task('html', function() {
  var plugins = [
      require('posthtml-lorem')(),
       ];
  // Gets .html and .nunjucks files in pages
  return gulp.src('./pages/**/*.+(html|nunjucks)')
  // Adding data to Nunjucks
  .pipe(data(function() {
    return require('./data.json')
  }))
  // Renders template with nunjucks
  .pipe(nunjucksRender({
      path: ['./helpers/']
    }))
  .pipe(posthtml(plugins))
  .pipe(mjml())
  // output files in app folder
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dest'))
});
```

This could be json file for data `data.json`

```
{
  "Page title": "hello English"
 }
```

I want to have two files in `./dest` folder `home.html` and `home_de.html`
And `home.html` should have content in English and `home_de.html` should have content in german. I don't want to have different source HTML template file for a different language.

Content to data file (`.json`) will be added manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gulp is just a simple wrapper around node.js.  By requiring fs you can access the file system.  Then you can loop through the different language data files and render the html for each one. This should do the trick, however this is untested, but you should get the gist.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var posthtml = require('gulp-posthtml');
var mjml = require('gulp-mjml');
var nunjucksRender = require('gulp-nunjucks-render');
var data = require('gulp-data');



gulp.task('html', function() {
    var plugins = [
       require('posthtml-lorem')(),
    ];

    fs.readdir('./languages/',function(err,files){
        if(err) throw err;
            files.forEach(function(file){
                var language = file.split('.')[0];
                // Gets .html and .nunjucks files in pages
                return gulp.src('./pages/**/*.+(html|nunjucks)')
                // Adding data to Nunjucks
                .pipe(data(function() {
                    return require('./languages/' + language + '.json')
                }))
                // Renders template with nunjucks
                .pipe(nunjucksRender({
                    path: ['./helpers/']
                }))
                .pipe(posthtml(plugins))
                .pipe(mjml())
                // output files in app folder
                .pipe(gulp.dest('./dest/' + language));
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What does folder /myfiles/ do, what it will have?

Comment: What should be the convention to keep language json file?

Comment: User preference question. Just name them after the language shortcode like en.json and de.json. As far as how you structure the object, that is all you man. Happy coding! ^_^

Comment: getting this message `The following tasks did not complete: html
[09:53:32] Did you forget to signal async completion?`?